# Jquery Unit Testing with Qunit and JSMockito (or other framework?), output isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, qunit

I'm new to unit testing in Javascript and am having some trouble adapting my understanding of unit testing from Java to Javascript. I have the code below that I am trying to do, basically I just want to mock the `divide` function. Currently, when I try it like this it just says there are no tests to run. I am open to suggestions of using a different mocking framework, I have been looking at a number of tutorials but just can't seem to wrap my head around javascript mocking. Any advice is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/git/qunit.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/git/qunit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://witnesstreefiles.s3.amazonaws.com/development/jsmockito-1.0.3-minified.js"></script>

  <script>
  function divide(a,b)
  {
    return a / b;
  }


  $(document).ready(function(){


      mockFunc = mockFunction();
      when(mockFunc)(anything()).then(function(arg) {
          return "foo ";
        });


      divide = mockFunc



        module("Basic Unit Test");
        test("Sample test", function()
        {
           expect(1);
           equals(divide(4,2),
            2,
            'Expected 2 as the result, result was: ' + divide(4,2));
        });
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit example</h1>
 <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
 <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>
 <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
 <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
 <div id="qunit-fixture">test markup, will be hidden</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two problems:

1) You need to include JsHamcrest: http://jshamcrest.destaquenet.com/
E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/downloads/danielfm/jshamcrest/jshamcrest-0.5.2-minified.js"></script>
```

2) You need to include both JsHamcrest and JsMockito into QUnit, by running the appropriate javascript functions (inside your script block is best):

```
JsHamcrest.Integration.QUnit();
JsMockito.Integration.QUnit();
```

cheers,
chris